# SP - check URL to have a source and redirect to source

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, url, redirect

I want to check my url to have a **source** and redirect to it.

I have a button for add a ListItem, i want where **doesn't have a source in URL** the page refresh, where **have a source in URL** --> redirect me to the source..

**This is my URL :**

```
http://ue-sps2/TestSite/Lists/linkBi/NewForm.aspx?RootFolder=%2FTestSite%2FLists%2FWayBill&ContentTypeId=0x0100AA8F1829F56BF44B89174066B393D0D0001DE65983974F8844815B824AF22378F0&Source=http%3A%2F%2Fsf%2Dspsdev02%2FTestSite%2FLists%2FWayBill%2FAllItems%2Easpx
```

**code redirect me to**

```
http://ue-sps2/TestSite/Lists/linkBi/NewForm.aspx
```

**I want to redirect me to** `Source=http%3A%2F%2Fsf%2Dspsdev02%2FTestSite%2FLists%2FlinkBi%2FAllItems%2Easpx`

```
http://ue-sps2/TestSite/Lists/linkBi/AllItems.aspx
```

Comment: Please add some of more details as it is unclear what are you trying which methodology you want to apply.

Comment: I added more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To go more precise I would like to code it in following manner.

```
if (Request.QueryString.Count > 0) {

    string urlSource = Request.QueryString["Source"];

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(urlSource))
    {
        int pos = urlSource.LastIndexOf(@"/");
        String newUrl = urlSource.Substring(0, pos + 1) + "/AllItems.aspx";
        SPUtility.Redirect(newUrl, SPRedirectFlags.Default, HttpContext.Current);
    }
}
```

Comment: updating the answer with your requirement

Comment: if my code is redirecting to http://sf-spsdev02/TestSite/Lists/WayBill/NewForm.aspx then it should definetly redirect to http://sf-spsdev02/TestSite/Lists/WayBill/AllItems.aspx .

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, then following is your requirement.

1. Checking  whether `Source` exists in query string or not
2. If it exists, then redirect to that URL

## Example

```
string source = Request.QueryString["Source"];

if (source != "")
{
   SPUtility.Redirect(source, SPRedirectFlags.Default, HttpContext.Current);
}
```